# Why can't I deploy UWP app on a new Lumia phone? (developer mode enabled)

Tags: windows-phone, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I created an app and I could run it on my Lumia 640 for testing. I have not submitted my App to Windows Store yet, as the debugging is unfinished. I just deployed it on my phone with `Developer Mode`enabled and it ran just fine.

But now I bought a new phone (same model), enabled `Developer Mode` and tried to deploy. However, **when I tried installing the App on the new phone, it won't display on my App list.** Restarting the phone did nothing, Logged in with my Microsoft account for the phone and nothing. I just don't know what I'm missing.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: What is exactly your install process? Simple build and deploy from Visual Studio or do you build the `.appx` and install it manually?

Comment: Deploy from VS and at least you'll have an error msg to look at.

Comment: @MateiRadu `.appx`, as I said copy the App to the phone manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm missing the files in `Dependencies` folder which will create with the .appx file.  I need to install these files first, and now all fine.